# Loading data in django project to new postgres database taking very long

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, database-migration

In my django project I am trying to migrate my database from sqlite to postgres. I've made a dump file of the database, changed my settings file to reflect the new database and now I want to upload this data to postgres. So initially I was running the following in the terminal:

`python manage.py loaddata data.json`

But this took very long - it was still running for more than a day, with no errors, and I eventually I stopped it.

So then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66159525/13290801) answer on SO, and therefore I created a `load_data.py` file, like so:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

import django
django.setup()
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.db import transaction

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='mysite.settings'

with transaction.atomic():
    call_command('loaddata', 'data.json')
```

And then ran it via `python load_data.py`. But it still takes incredibly long and the data has not loaded. My data file is 20.8MB. Is there anything that I can do to speed things up?

For reference, the model that has the most data looks like this:

```
class WordManager(models.Manager):
    def search(self, query=None):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        if query is not None:
            or_lookup = (Q(target_word__icontains=query) | 
                         Q(source_word__icontains=query)|
                         Q(example_sentence__icontains=query) 
                        )
            qs = qs.filter(or_lookup).distinct() # distinct() is often necessary with Q lookups
        return qs

class Word(models.Model):
    objects = WordManager()
    target_word = models.CharField('Word in Russian', max_length=35,help_text="The word you want to add, in Russian")
    source_word = models.CharField('What does it mean?',max_length=35, help_text="Write down the translation in any language", blank=False, null=True)
    add_to_word_list = models.BooleanField('Would you like to create a flashcard?', default=True)
    deck_name = models.CharField('Deck name', max_length=25, default="My Words")
    category = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=True,help_text="Create a custom category for this word, e.g. Food")
    example_sentence = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=True,help_text="It's important to learn words in context!")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="words",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.target_word

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("vocab:detail",
        kwargs={"username": self.user.username, "pk": self.pk})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["target_word"]

        ## constrain user to add only one instance of target word
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user','target_word', 'source_word'],name='unique_word')]


from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from api.models import Flashcard, Deck

@receiver(post_save, sender=Word)
def create_deck(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance._meta.model.objects.all()
        deck_name = instance.deck_name
        user = instance.user
        flash_wanted = Word.objects.filter(add_to_word_list=True)
        if flash_wanted:
            deck_name, created = Deck.objects.get_or_create(owner=user, name=deck_name)

post_save.connect(create_deck, sender=Word)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Word)
def flash_from_word(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
    if created:
        flash_wanted = Word.objects.filter(add_to_word_list=True)
        instance._meta.model.objects.all()
        target_word = instance.target_word
        source_word = instance.source_word
        deck_name = instance.deck_name
        user = instance.user
        if flash_wanted:
            flash = Flashcard.objects.create(owner=user, question=target_word,answer=source_word,deck=Deck.objects.get(name=deck_name,owner=user))

post_save.connect(flash_from_word, sender=Word)
```